Filter Pandas DataFrame when all IDs are blank
This is how I am populating my DataFrame:
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID1': ['BBG01Q69DW37', 'BBG01Q69DW37','BBG01Q69TEST','BBG01Q69TES1'],
        'ID2': ['YU3384903', 'YU3384903','','YU338TES1'],
        'ID3': ['ES0413860877', 'ES0413860877','','ES041386TES1']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I wanted to exclude only those records when all ID1, ID2 and ID3 are all blank.
I tried using the code below:
df = df[(df['ID1'] != '') & (df['ID2'] != '') & (df['ID3'] != '')]
print(df)

Here is the output:
   ID1           ID2        ID3
0  BBG01Q69DW37  YU3384903  ES0413860877
1  BBG01Q69DW37  YU3384903  ES0413860877
3  BBG01Q69TES1  YU338TES1  ES041386TES1

If any of the IDs are present it should display the whole row.
For this example, I wanted to display output for BBG01Q69TEST as there is an ID1 present even though the corresponding ID2 and ID3 are blank.

df[~df.eq('').all(axis=1)] or df[~df[['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']].eq('').all(axis=1)] if you have more columns than these

A possible solution, whose steps are:

The eq method checks if each element in the dataframe is equal to an empty string ''.

The any method is then used along axis=1 to check if any element in each row is an empty string.

The tilde ~ operator inverts the boolean values, so rows with any empty strings become False.

Finally, loc is used to select only the rows where the condition is True.


df.loc[~df.eq('').any(axis=1)]

Output:
            ID1        ID2           ID3
0  BBG01Q69DW37  YU3384903  ES0413860877
1  BBG01Q69DW37  YU3384903  ES0413860877
3  BBG01Q69TES1  YU338TES1  ES041386TES1


This will work if dataframe has ID1, ID2 and ID3 And I wanted to check blank on all three. However if there is one more ID4 in dataframe which I dont want to consider as a part of filter that means ID1, ID2, ID3 and ID4 are in dataframe but filter is only for ID1, ID2 and ID3. For that .any wont work.

In that case, just use: df.loc[~df[['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']].eq('').any(axis=1)]
